# Simplewallet: Can I print the current values of the options that can be set by the "set" command?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I did not see something like a "get" command, and for example "set auto-refresh" without an argument does not show the current status of auto-refresh.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just type "set" by itself. All the current values are displayed.

Comment: I tried that, too, but I get `Error: set: needs an argument. available options: seed, always-confirm-transfers, default-mixin, auto-refresh, refresh-type`. I'm running 0.9.4 binaries, maybe your answer refers to the current master branch on github?

Comment: Ah yes indeed. I didn't realize this was added so recently to the codebase. This was added in April, from PR#826

Comment: Ok, thanks, then I'm looking forward to the next release :-)